# How can I make this url more beautiful using .htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

So I have a website with projects and they all have a page with an id now my current url to get a project is this:

```
domain.com/subfolder/index.php?page=projects&id=02
```

So my goal is to get:

```
domain.com/subfolder/$page/$id
domain.com/subfolder/projects/02
```

I currently have the .htaccess in the subfolder, but I dont have a lot of knowledge about htaccess so please help me out!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following rule:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^subfolder/([^/]*)/([^/]*)$ /subfolder/index.php?page=$1&id=$2 [L]
```

That will leave you with the following URL:

`http://domain.com/subfolder/projects/02`

Comment: No problem, glad I could help :)